# Why does the `eval` function seemingly take so long in Python?

Tags: python

**TL;DR why is Python's `eval` function slow?**

Hi. I was solving a coding exercise and noticed that the `eval` function was causing timeouts for some test cases and was wondering why this is the case as I don't particularly recall reading that the function is slow.

Here's the exercise:

> You are given a list of *n* nonnegative integers and a target integer. Find out how many possible ways there are to add '+' or '-' in between the provided integers in order to obtain the target. For example, the input `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]` and `3` would return `5` since there are five total ways to insert + or - to obtain `3`: `-1+1+1+1+1`, `+1-1+1+1+1`, `+1+1-1+1+1`, `+1+1+1-1+1`, `+1+1+1+1-1`.

The solution I initially came up with used `eval` as follows:

```
from itertools import product
from typing import List


def solution(numbers: List[int], target: int) -> int:
    numbers = [str(x) for x in numbers]
    length = len(numbers)
    all_operations = list(map(''.join, product('+-', repeat=length)))

    answer = 0
    for operation in all_operations:
        eval_string = ''.join([''.join(x) for x in zip(operation, numbers)])

        if eval(eval_string) == target:
            answer += 1

    return answer
```

The second solution that passes all test cases doesn't use `eval` and simply performs the arithmetic step by step:

```
from itertools import product
from typing import List


def solution(numbers: List[int], target: int) -> int:
    numbers = [str(x) for x in numbers]
    
    length = len(numbers)
    all_signs = list(map(''.join, product('+-', repeat=length)))
    
    answer = 0
    for operation in all_signs:
        value = 0

        for op, number in zip(operation, numbers):
            if op == '+':
                value += int(number)
            elif op == '-':
                value -= int(number)
                
        if value == target:
            answer += 1
    
    return answer
```

Comment: `eval` has to analyse and interpret the string it is given. Doing that is slower than not doing it.

Comment: You are comparing code that is already compiled (when your app is running) to code that has yet to be evaluated at runtime - that's comparing apples to bananas.

Comment: @MikeScotty Sorry, but I'm not quite following; would using the `eval` function refer to the code that has to be evaluated during runtime?

Comment: The `eval` function has to read the code, convert it to bytecode, during the time of execution, each and every time in the loop.. meanwhile, a python script converts all of the code into bytecode once before execution (this isn't compilation by the way), anyhow, converting to bytecode is a resource intensive operation, that is exactly why it is normally done once before the code is run.

Answer (score 0):

Converting your values to strings then running *eval* is not going to be efficient. This will be faster although it may be possible to improve this even further:

```
import itertools

INTS = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
CONST = 3
# build a new list comprised of the original INTS plus their negative values
P = list(map(lambda x: -x, INTS)) + INTS
# work out the unique permutations
s = set(itertools.permutations(P, len(INTS)))
# iterate over (map) each unique permutations to see if its sum matches CONST
print(list(map(lambda x: sum(x) == CONST, s)).count(True))
```